# Is there a shorter way to increment bd_address in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a python's function to increment BT device BD_ADDR by any value but my function can only work up to xx:xx:xx:xx:FE:FF.  For example, original BD_ADDR = AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF --> incremented by 1 BD_ADDR = AA:BB:CC:DD:EF:00.  Also is there a shorter way to do this without all if statements?  any suggestions will be appreciated. 
 Below is the script:

```
def ba_incr(mac,incr):
        old_bytes = mac[12:].split(":")
        if (old_bytes[0] != "00"):
             if (old_bytes[0] != "01" and old_bytes[0] != "0F"):
                  old_hex = str(old_bytes[0] + old_bytes[1])
                  incr_hex = hex(int(str(int(old_hex, base=16) + incr)))[2:]
                  new_bytes = str(incr_hex[:2]) + ":" + str(incr_hex[2:])
             elif (old_bytes[0] == "0F" and old_bytes[1] == "FF") :
                  old_hex = str(old_bytes[0] + old_bytes[1])
                  incr_hex = hex(int(str(int(old_hex, base=16) + incr)))[2:]

                  new_bytes = str(incr_hex[:2]) + ":" + str(incr_hex[2:])
                else:
                        old_hex = str(old_bytes[0] + old_bytes[1])
                        incr_hex = hex(int(str(int(old_hex, base=16) + incr)))[2:]
                        #print ("incremented hex",incr_hex)
                        new_bytes = "0" + str(incr_hex[:1]) + ":" + str(incr_hex[1:])
        elif (old_bytes[0] == "00" and old_bytes[1] == "FF"):
                old_hex = old_bytes[1]
                #print ("old hex:",old_hex)
                incr_hex = hex(int(str(int(old_hex, base=16) + incr)))[2:]
                #print ("incremented hex:",incr_hex)
                new_bytes = "01" + ":" + str(incr_hex[1:])
        elif (old_bytes[0] == "00" and old_bytes[1][:1] == "0") and old_bytes[1][1:] != "F":
                old_hex = old_bytes[1]
                #print ("old hex:",old_hex)
                incr_hex = hex(int(str(int(old_hex, base=16) + incr)))[2:]
                #print ("incremented hex:",incr_hex)
                new_bytes = old_bytes[0] + ":0" + str(incr_hex)
        elif (old_bytes[0] == "00" and old_bytes[1] != "FF"):
                old_hex = old_bytes[1]
                #print ("old hex:",old_hex)
                incr_hex = hex(int(str(int(old_hex, base=16) + incr)))[2:]
                #print ("incremented hex:",incr_hex)
                new_bytes = old_bytes[0] + ":" + str(incr_hex)[:2]
        print ("mac after:", mac[:12] + new_bytes.upper())
```

Comment: Can you explain what the code is meant to do, without any acronyms which aren't ubiquitous?

Comment: the code was meant to extract last 2 bytes of bd addr and increment by any preselected value such as 1, 2, or 3.  and produce a new incremented bd addr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably try something like this:

1. Remove the ':' from the mac address
2. Convert the mac address to integer
3. Increment the integer value
4. Convert the integer to hex string
5. Insert back the ':' at the appropriate positions

Sample code that worked for me (for simplicity I am incrementing by 1). You may need to modify it to handle corner cases.

```
s = 'AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF'
s = s.replace(':', '')
val = int(s, 16)
val = val + 1
incr_s = hex(val)
incr_s = incr_s[2:].upper()
incr_s = ':'.join(incr_s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(incr_s), 2))
print(s)
print(incr_s)
```

Output:

```
AABBCCDDEEFF
AA:BB:CC:DD:EF:00
```